# Is there an integral domain containing an element having no factorization into irreducible elements?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I know that the ring of algebraic integers can be an answer because this ring has no irreducible elements.

> So, is there an integral domain with nonempty set of irreducible elements and an element having no factorization into irreducibles?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078464/algebraic-integers-form-a-ring-without-any-irreducible-elements-every-prime-ide

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714719. This shows that such an example should be non-Noetherian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $R=\{P \in \mathbb{Q}[X],\, P(0) \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. $R$ has irreducible elements, such as $X^2+1$. However, $X$ has no factorisation into a product of irreducible elements. Indeed, any factorisation of $X$ is of the form $n \cdot \frac{X}{n}$, and $\frac{X}{n}$ is never irreducible (it can be written as $\frac{X}{(n+1)!} \frac{(n+1)!}{n}$ and none of the factors are units).